# Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead - Swift Codable

Tags: json, swift, codable

I am trying to debug an error message from Codable, but I don't see the error anywhere in my code. Hoping someone can help.

My data model looks like this:

```
final class Amenity : Codable {
    var id: String
    var hasChildren: Bool
    var name: String
    var fullName: String?
    var phone: String?
    var redirectLink: String?
    var moreInfoLink: String?
    var description: String?
    var businessDays: [BusinessDays] = []
    var children: [Amenity] = []

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case businessDays = "businessdays"
        case hasChildren = "hasChild"
        case name = "name"
        case phone = "phoneNumer"
        case moreInfoLink = "moreInfoLink"
        case redirectLink = "redirectLink"
        case fullName = "fullName"
        case description = "desc"
        case children = "children"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        businessDays = try values.decodeIfPresent([BusinessDays].self, forKey: .businessDays) ?? [BusinessDays]()
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        children = try values.decodeIfPresent([Amenity].self, forKey: .children) ?? [Amenity]()
        hasChildren = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .hasChildren) ?? false
        phone = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .phone)
        fullName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .fullName)
        redirectLink = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .redirectLink)
        description = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .description)
        moreInfoLink = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .moreInfoLink)

    }
}

final class BusinessDays: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var hours: [Hour]
    var daysOfWeek: String
    var displayName: String?
}

final class Hour: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var startTime: String
    var endTime: String
    var groupName: String
}
```

The JSON is this:

```
 [
        {
            "businessdays": [],
            "_id": "5e18e270147424000e337acc",
            "fullName": "MV - Dining",
            "name": "Dining & Cafés",
            "phoneNumber": "",
            "createdAt": "2020-01-10T20:45:36.459Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-01-14T22:25:01.066Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "campus": "5e00fe557ecc0b000e1c0fa1",
            "hasChild": true,
            "children": [
                {
                    "businessdays": [
                        {
                            "hours": [
                                {
                                    "_id": "5e13d9389f25816614f84563",
                                    "name": "Breakfast-7-10",
                                    "startTime": "7 AM",
                                    "endTime": "10 AM",
                                    "createdAt": "2020-01-07T01:04:56.255Z",
                                    "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:46:44.667Z",
                                    "__v": 0,
                                    "groupName": "Breakfast",
                                    "id": "5e13d9389f25816614f84563"
                                },
                                {
                                    "_id": "5e1cc2ebd40bf0000e83af64",
                                    "name": "Lunch-1130-230",
                                    "startTime": "11:30 AM",
                                    "endTime": "2:30 PM",
                                    "groupName": "Lunch",
                                    "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:20:11.513Z",
                                    "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:46:54.041Z",
                                    "__v": 0,
                                    "id": "5e1cc2ebd40bf0000e83af64"
                                },
                                {
                                    "_id": "5e1cc311d40bf0000e83af65",
                                    "name": "Dinner-430-7",
                                    "startTime": "4:30 PM",
                                    "endTime": "7 PM",
                                    "groupName": "Dinner",
                                    "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:20:49.468Z",
                                    "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:47:27.836Z",
                                    "__v": 0,
                                    "id": "5e1cc311d40bf0000e83af65"
                                }
                            ],
                            "_id": "5e13d9479f25816614f84564",
                            "name": "El Camino Cafe - Weekday",
                            "daysOfWeek": "2,3,4,5,6",
                            "displayName": "Weekday",
                            "createdAt": "2020-01-07T01:05:11.305Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:45:18.357Z",
                            "__v": 0,
                            "id": "5e13d9479f25816614f84564"
                        },
                        {
                            "hours": [
                                {
                                    "_id": "5e13d9389f25816614f84563",
                                    "name": "Breakfast-7-10",
                                    "startTime": "7 AM",
                                    "endTime": "10 AM",
                                    "createdAt": "2020-01-07T01:04:56.255Z",
                                    "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:46:44.667Z",
                                    "__v": 0,
                                    "groupName": "Breakfast",
                                    "id": "5e13d9389f25816614f84563"
                                },
                                {
                                    "_id": "5e1cc2ebd40bf0000e83af64",
                                    "name": "Lunch-1130-230",
                                    "startTime": "11:30 AM",
                                    "endTime": "2:30 PM",
                                    "groupName": "Lunch",
                                    "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:20:11.513Z",
                                    "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:46:54.041Z",
                                    "__v": 0,
                                    "id": "5e1cc2ebd40bf0000e83af64"
                                },
                                {
                                    "_id": "5e1cc311d40bf0000e83af65",
                                    "name": "Dinner-430-7",
                                    "startTime": "4:30 PM",
                                    "endTime": "7 PM",
                                    "groupName": "Dinner",
                                    "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:20:49.468Z",
                                    "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:47:27.836Z",
                                    "__v": 0,
                                    "id": "5e1cc311d40bf0000e83af65"
                                }
                            ],
                            "_id": "5e1cc278d40bf0000e83af63",
                            "name": "El Camino Cafe - Weekend",
                            "daysOfWeek": "1,7",
                            "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:18:16.931Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:44:39.106Z",
                            "__v": 0,
                            "displayName": "Weekend",
                            "id": "5e1cc278d40bf0000e83af63"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "5e0a4fb06f894a44bbc0d238",
                    "name": "El Camino Café",
                    "phoneNumber": "",
                    "createdAt": "2019-12-30T19:27:44.544Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-01-14T21:27:39.516Z",
                    "__v": 0,
                    "campus": "5e00fe557ecc0b000e1c0fa1",
                    "campusName": "Mountain View",
                    "desc": "The cafeteria is located on the ground floor of the new main hospital. Salads, sandwiches, hot meals, breakfast items, desserts, beverages and snacks are available during hours noted below.",
                    "fullName": "MV - El Camino Café",
                    "photo": "/uploads/f7db0b70f3c84e7cba8bc3b269ed0241.jpg",
                    "id": "5e0a4fb06f894a44bbc0d238"
                },
                {
                    "businessdays": [],
                    "_id": "5e0a4fc26f894a44bbc0d239",
                    "name": "The Bistro",
                    "phoneNumber": "",
                    "createdAt": "2019-12-30T19:28:02.427Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-01-14T21:35:21.618Z",
                    "__v": 0,
                    "campus": "5e00fe557ecc0b000e1c0fa1",
                    "campusName": "Mountain View",
                    "desc": "The Bistro is located on the ground floor of the main hospital. Featuring gourmet coffee from Moksha Coffee Roasting, a local business focused on providing sustainable and shade grown coffee. Other offerings include fresh fruit smoothies, breakfast items, sandwiches, soup, salads, desserts and more. Vegetarian and gluten-free options are available daily. Dine in our cozy seating area or grab something to go.",
                    "fullName": "MV - The Bistro",
                    "photo": "/uploads/44e81fa1abba45f69d10e61cf63b306f.jpg",
                    "id": "5e0a4fc26f894a44bbc0d239"
                },
                {
                    "businessdays": [],
                    "_id": "5e1e344cbf265e000eb355c4",
                    "name": "Java Junction",
                    "fullName": "MV - Java Junction",
                    "desc": "Java Junction offers a wide variety of espresso and tea drinks featuring Starbucks Coffee. Pre-packaged snacks, muffins, cookies, croissants and fruit are also available.",
                    "createdAt": "2020-01-14T21:36:12.423Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-01-14T21:36:12.542Z",
                    "__v": 0,
                    "campus": "5e00fe557ecc0b000e1c0fa1",
                    "photo": "/uploads/37f75a8019804503b7bd24e80cb12ff6.jpg",
                    "id": "5e1e344cbf265e000eb355c4"
                }
            ],
            "photo": null,
            "id": "5e18e270147424000e337acc"
        },
        {
            "businessdays": [],
            "_id": "5e1cc774d40bf0000e83af66",
            "name": "Library",
            "moreInfoLink": "https://www.elcaminohealth.org/services/health-library-resource-center/health-library-services",
            "desc": "You can use the services at the Health Library & Resource Center, located on the main floor of the hospital, in person, over the phone or online. If you visit or call, you will be assisted by the same professional research librarians who support the information needs of physicians and nurses at the hospital.",
            "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:39:32.894Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:40:54.451Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "campus": "5e00fe557ecc0b000e1c0fa1",
            "fullName": "MV - Library",
            "children": [],
            "photo": "/uploads/432f2255abe84c46b0d2cfe736a2b9ba.jpeg",
            "id": "5e1cc774d40bf0000e83af66"
        },
        {
            "businessdays": [],
            "_id": "5e1cc7bad40bf0000e83af69",
            "name": "Gift shops",
            "hasChild": true,
            "fullName": "MV - Gift Shops",
            "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:40:42.178Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:40:42.294Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "campus": "5e00fe557ecc0b000e1c0fa1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "businessdays": [
                        {
                            "hours": [
                                {
                                    "_id": "5e1cc9a9d40bf0000e83af6c",
                                    "name": "Weekday-9-6",
                                    "startTime": "9 AM",
                                    "endTime": "6 PM",
                                    "groupName": "Weekday",
                                    "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:48:57.988Z",
                                    "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:48:58.065Z",
                                    "__v": 0,
                                    "id": "5e1cc9a9d40bf0000e83af6c"
                                }
                            ],
                            "_id": "5e1cc87fd40bf0000e83af6b",
                            "name": "The Gift Connection - Weekday",
                            "daysOfWeek": "2,3,4,5,6",
                            "displayName": "Weekday",
                            "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:43:59.089Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:50:46.506Z",
                            "__v": 0,
                            "id": "5e1cc87fd40bf0000e83af6b"
                        },
                        {
                            "hours": [
                                {
                                    "_id": "5e1cc9ded40bf0000e83af6d",
                                    "name": "Weekend-10-4",
                                    "startTime": "10 AM",
                                    "endTime": "4 PM",
                                    "groupName": "Weekend and Holiday",
                                    "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:49:50.956Z",
                                    "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:49:51.034Z",
                                    "__v": 0,
                                    "id": "5e1cc9ded40bf0000e83af6d"
                                }
                            ],
                            "_id": "5e1cca40d40bf0000e83af6e",
                            "name": "The Gift Connection - Weekend",
                            "daysOfWeek": "1,7",
                            "displayName": "Weekend",
                            "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:51:28.677Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:51:28.753Z",
                            "__v": 0,
                            "id": "5e1cca40d40bf0000e83af6e"
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "5e1cc83dd40bf0000e83af6a",
                    "name": "The Gift Connection",
                    "phoneNumber": "650-962-5873",
                    "desc": "The Gift Connection, located in the main hospital lobby, carries convenience items, books, newspapers, magazines, fresh floral arrangements, greeting cards and a variety of gift items. You can order a plant or floral bouquet from our gift shop over the phone with a credit card and get same-day or next-day delivery to a patient’s room at no extra cost.",
                    "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:42:53.989Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-01-14T22:27:58.203Z",
                    "__v": 0,
                    "campus": "5e00fe557ecc0b000e1c0fa1",
                    "photo": "/uploads/71afd31fa1764523ad999c11ffd0b016.jpeg",
                    "id": "5e1cc83dd40bf0000e83af6a"
                }
            ],
            "photo": null,
            "id": "5e1cc7bad40bf0000e83af69"
        },
        {
            "businessdays": [],
            "_id": "5e1e45d0bf265e000eb355c9",
            "name": "Massage",
            "fullName": "MV - Massage",
            "desc": "Massage can relieve stress and pain and improve circulation and healing. As a special service to our patients, we provide free, 15-minute massages by an experienced, massage therapist. You need to receive approval from your doctor beforehand. To schedule an appointment, let your nurse know that you’re interested.",
            "createdAt": "2020-01-14T22:50:56.920Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-01-14T22:50:57.046Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "campus": "5e00fe557ecc0b000e1c0fa1",
            "children": [],
            "photo": "/uploads/451ca56b17a94c73a1b447c4e967c50a.jpeg",
            "id": "5e1e45d0bf265e000eb355c9"
        },
        {
            "businessdays": [],
            "_id": "5e1e515bbf265e000eb355cc",
            "name": "Music & healing",
            "fullName": "MV - Music & healing",
            "phoneNumber": "650-962-5836",
            "desc": "Through the Healing Arts Program, we bring the soothing sounds of jazz, classical guitar, Celtic and double-strung harp, piano and voice to the bedside to create warmth and comfort to our hospital. Professional musicians go from ward to ward, playing in hallways and along bedsides for patients, staff and visitors.\n\nProfessional musicians who visit our campuses include:\n\nJeff Buenz, who plays Latin and jazz guitar and bass.\nBarbary Grant, who plays Celtic music and traditional songs on the Irish harp.\nDona Reyes, who plays classical Spanish guitar music.\nDavid Snellbacher, who plays an assortment of guitar music including old English, Celtic, classical and traditional Christmas carols and contemporary music.\nTo arrange a visit during your stay, call guest services at 650-962-5836.",
            "createdAt": "2020-01-14T23:40:11.206Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-01-14T23:40:29.049Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "campus": "5e00fe557ecc0b000e1c0fa1",
            "children": [],
            "photo": "/uploads/7b12ed03a6f342caae96d6e69df8180a.jpg",
            "id": "5e1e515bbf265e000eb355cc"
        }
    ]
```

I get this error: Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead when trying to decode the JSON. I don't see any dictionary though, so I'm confused why it would throw this. Any thoughts?

API:

```
func getAmenities(for campus: String, handler: @escaping (([Amenity]?, Error?) -> Void)) {
    let url = "/amenities"
    //"campus": campus
    let params: Parameters = [:]
    NetworkManager.shared().get(url, parameters: params, endpoint: .cms) { data, error in
        if data != nil {
            do {
                let amenities = try JSONDecoder().decode([Amenity].self, from: data!)
                handler(amenities, nil)
            } catch {
                handler(nil, error)
            }
        }
        handler(nil, error)
    }
}
```

Network manager:

```
private func requestPath(_ relativeUrl: String, endpoint: Endpoint) -> URL {
    return URL(string: endpoint.rawValue + relativeUrl)!
}

func get(_ relativeUrl: String, parameters: Parameters, endpoint: Endpoint, handler: @escaping ((Data?, Error?) -> Void)) {
    Alamofire.request(requestPath(relativeUrl, endpoint: endpoint),
                    method: .get,
                    parameters: parameters,
                    encoding: URLEncoding.queryString,
                    headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            handler(response.data, nil)
        case .failure(let error):
            handler(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Swift error:

```
Printing description of error:
▿ DecodingError
  ▿ typeMismatch : 2 elements
    - .0 : Swift.Array<Any>
    ▿ .1 : Context
      - codingPath : 0 elements
      - debugDescription : "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead."
      - underlyingError : nil
```

Comment: Please add the full error. It describes also the location where the error occurs

Answer (score 1):

Are you attempting to decode a single `Amenity` or an array of them?

The JSON includes an array of them, so you should be doing something like this (with `[Amenity].self` -- note the brackets -- which decodes an array of `Amenity`):

```swift
let amenities = try! decoder.decode([Amenity].self, from: json)
```

not with `Amenity.self` (which decodes a single instance `Amenity`).

**Update**
I don't receive any errors when I attempt to decode an array of `Amenity`. You can try with this playground.

```swift
import Foundation

let json = """
[
    {
        "businessdays": [],
        "_id": "5e18e270147424000e337acc",
        "fullName": "MV - Dining",
        "name": "Dining & Cafés",
        "phoneNumber": "",
        "createdAt": "2020-01-10T20:45:36.459Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-01-14T22:25:01.066Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "campus": "5e00fe557ecc0b000e1c0fa1",
        "hasChild": true,
        "children": [
            {
                "businessdays": [
                    {
                        "hours": [
                            {
                                "_id": "5e13d9389f25816614f84563",
                                "name": "Breakfast-7-10",
                                "startTime": "7 AM",
                                "endTime": "10 AM",
                                "createdAt": "2020-01-07T01:04:56.255Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:46:44.667Z",
                                "__v": 0,
                                "groupName": "Breakfast",
                                "id": "5e13d9389f25816614f84563"
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "5e1cc2ebd40bf0000e83af64",
                                "name": "Lunch-1130-230",
                                "startTime": "11:30 AM",
                                "endTime": "2:30 PM",
                                "groupName": "Lunch",
                                "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:20:11.513Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:46:54.041Z",
                                "__v": 0,
                                "id": "5e1cc2ebd40bf0000e83af64"
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "5e1cc311d40bf0000e83af65",
                                "name": "Dinner-430-7",
                                "startTime": "4:30 PM",
                                "endTime": "7 PM",
                                "groupName": "Dinner",
                                "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:20:49.468Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:47:27.836Z",
                                "__v": 0,
                                "id": "5e1cc311d40bf0000e83af65"
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id": "5e13d9479f25816614f84564",
                        "name": "El Camino Cafe - Weekday",
                        "daysOfWeek": "2,3,4,5,6",
                        "displayName": "Weekday",
                        "createdAt": "2020-01-07T01:05:11.305Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:45:18.357Z",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "id": "5e13d9479f25816614f84564"
                    },
                    {
                        "hours": [
                            {
                                "_id": "5e13d9389f25816614f84563",
                                "name": "Breakfast-7-10",
                                "startTime": "7 AM",
                                "endTime": "10 AM",
                                "createdAt": "2020-01-07T01:04:56.255Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:46:44.667Z",
                                "__v": 0,
                                "groupName": "Breakfast",
                                "id": "5e13d9389f25816614f84563"
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "5e1cc2ebd40bf0000e83af64",
                                "name": "Lunch-1130-230",
                                "startTime": "11:30 AM",
                                "endTime": "2:30 PM",
                                "groupName": "Lunch",
                                "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:20:11.513Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:46:54.041Z",
                                "__v": 0,
                                "id": "5e1cc2ebd40bf0000e83af64"
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "5e1cc311d40bf0000e83af65",
                                "name": "Dinner-430-7",
                                "startTime": "4:30 PM",
                                "endTime": "7 PM",
                                "groupName": "Dinner",
                                "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:20:49.468Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:47:27.836Z",
                                "__v": 0,
                                "id": "5e1cc311d40bf0000e83af65"
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id": "5e1cc278d40bf0000e83af63",
                        "name": "El Camino Cafe - Weekend",
                        "daysOfWeek": "1,7",
                        "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:18:16.931Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:44:39.106Z",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "displayName": "Weekend",
                        "id": "5e1cc278d40bf0000e83af63"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5e0a4fb06f894a44bbc0d238",
                "name": "El Camino Café",
                "phoneNumber": "",
                "createdAt": "2019-12-30T19:27:44.544Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-01-14T21:27:39.516Z",
                "__v": 0,
                "campus": "5e00fe557ecc0b000e1c0fa1",
                "campusName": "Mountain View",
                "desc": "The cafeteria is located on the ground floor of the new main hospital. Salads, sandwiches, hot meals, breakfast items, desserts, beverages and snacks are available during hours noted below.",
                "fullName": "MV - El Camino Café",
                "photo": "/uploads/f7db0b70f3c84e7cba8bc3b269ed0241.jpg",
                "id": "5e0a4fb06f894a44bbc0d238"
            },
            {
                "businessdays": [],
                "_id": "5e0a4fc26f894a44bbc0d239",
                "name": "The Bistro",
                "phoneNumber": "",
                "createdAt": "2019-12-30T19:28:02.427Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-01-14T21:35:21.618Z",
                "__v": 0,
                "campus": "5e00fe557ecc0b000e1c0fa1",
                "campusName": "Mountain View",
                "desc": "The Bistro is located on the ground floor of the main hospital. Featuring gourmet coffee from Moksha Coffee Roasting, a local business focused on providing sustainable and shade grown coffee. Other offerings include fresh fruit smoothies, breakfast items, sandwiches, soup, salads, desserts and more. Vegetarian and gluten-free options are available daily. Dine in our cozy seating area or grab something to go.",
                "fullName": "MV - The Bistro",
                "photo": "/uploads/44e81fa1abba45f69d10e61cf63b306f.jpg",
                "id": "5e0a4fc26f894a44bbc0d239"
            },
            {
                "businessdays": [],
                "_id": "5e1e344cbf265e000eb355c4",
                "name": "Java Junction",
                "fullName": "MV - Java Junction",
                "desc": "Java Junction offers a wide variety of espresso and tea drinks featuring Starbucks Coffee. Pre-packaged snacks, muffins, cookies, croissants and fruit are also available.",
                "createdAt": "2020-01-14T21:36:12.423Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-01-14T21:36:12.542Z",
                "__v": 0,
                "campus": "5e00fe557ecc0b000e1c0fa1",
                "photo": "/uploads/37f75a8019804503b7bd24e80cb12ff6.jpg",
                "id": "5e1e344cbf265e000eb355c4"
            }
        ],
        "photo": null,
        "id": "5e18e270147424000e337acc"
    },
    {
        "businessdays": [],
        "_id": "5e1cc774d40bf0000e83af66",
        "name": "Library",
        "moreInfoLink": "https://www.elcaminohealth.org/services/health-library-resource-center/health-library-services",
        "desc": "You can use the services at the Health Library & Resource Center, located on the main floor of the hospital, in person, over the phone or online. If you visit or call, you will be assisted by the same professional research librarians who support the information needs of physicians and nurses at the hospital.",
        "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:39:32.894Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:40:54.451Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "campus": "5e00fe557ecc0b000e1c0fa1",
        "fullName": "MV - Library",
        "children": [],
        "photo": "/uploads/432f2255abe84c46b0d2cfe736a2b9ba.jpeg",
        "id": "5e1cc774d40bf0000e83af66"
    },
    {
        "businessdays": [],
        "_id": "5e1cc7bad40bf0000e83af69",
        "name": "Gift shops",
        "hasChild": true,
        "fullName": "MV - Gift Shops",
        "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:40:42.178Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:40:42.294Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "campus": "5e00fe557ecc0b000e1c0fa1",
        "children": [
            {
                "businessdays": [
                    {
                        "hours": [
                            {
                                "_id": "5e1cc9a9d40bf0000e83af6c",
                                "name": "Weekday-9-6",
                                "startTime": "9 AM",
                                "endTime": "6 PM",
                                "groupName": "Weekday",
                                "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:48:57.988Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:48:58.065Z",
                                "__v": 0,
                                "id": "5e1cc9a9d40bf0000e83af6c"
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id": "5e1cc87fd40bf0000e83af6b",
                        "name": "The Gift Connection - Weekday",
                        "daysOfWeek": "2,3,4,5,6",
                        "displayName": "Weekday",
                        "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:43:59.089Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:50:46.506Z",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "id": "5e1cc87fd40bf0000e83af6b"
                    },
                    {
                        "hours": [
                            {
                                "_id": "5e1cc9ded40bf0000e83af6d",
                                "name": "Weekend-10-4",
                                "startTime": "10 AM",
                                "endTime": "4 PM",
                                "groupName": "Weekend and Holiday",
                                "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:49:50.956Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:49:51.034Z",
                                "__v": 0,
                                "id": "5e1cc9ded40bf0000e83af6d"
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id": "5e1cca40d40bf0000e83af6e",
                        "name": "The Gift Connection - Weekend",
                        "daysOfWeek": "1,7",
                        "displayName": "Weekend",
                        "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:51:28.677Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T19:51:28.753Z",
                        "__v": 0,
                        "id": "5e1cca40d40bf0000e83af6e"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5e1cc83dd40bf0000e83af6a",
                "name": "The Gift Connection",
                "phoneNumber": "650-962-5873",
                "desc": "The Gift Connection, located in the main hospital lobby, carries convenience items, books, newspapers, magazines, fresh floral arrangements, greeting cards and a variety of gift items. You can order a plant or floral bouquet from our gift shop over the phone with a credit card and get same-day or next-day delivery to a patient’s room at no extra cost.",
                "createdAt": "2020-01-13T19:42:53.989Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-01-14T22:27:58.203Z",
                "__v": 0,
                "campus": "5e00fe557ecc0b000e1c0fa1",
                "photo": "/uploads/71afd31fa1764523ad999c11ffd0b016.jpeg",
                "id": "5e1cc83dd40bf0000e83af6a"
            }
        ],
        "photo": null,
        "id": "5e1cc7bad40bf0000e83af69"
    },
    {
        "businessdays": [],
        "_id": "5e1e45d0bf265e000eb355c9",
        "name": "Massage",
        "fullName": "MV - Massage",
        "desc": "Massage can relieve stress and pain and improve circulation and healing. As a special service to our patients, we provide free, 15-minute massages by an experienced, massage therapist. You need to receive approval from your doctor beforehand. To schedule an appointment, let your nurse know that you’re interested.",
        "createdAt": "2020-01-14T22:50:56.920Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-01-14T22:50:57.046Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "campus": "5e00fe557ecc0b000e1c0fa1",
        "children": [],
        "photo": "/uploads/451ca56b17a94c73a1b447c4e967c50a.jpeg",
        "id": "5e1e45d0bf265e000eb355c9"
    },
    {
        "businessdays": [],
        "_id": "5e1e515bbf265e000eb355cc",
        "name": "Music & healing",
        "fullName": "MV - Music & healing",
        "phoneNumber": "650-962-5836",
        "desc": "Through the Healing Arts Program, we bring the soothing sounds of jazz, classical guitar, Celtic and double-strung harp, piano and voice to the bedside to create warmth and comfort to our hospital. Professional musicians go from ward to ward, playing in hallways and along bedsides for patients, staff and visitors.\\n\\nProfessional musicians who visit our campuses include:\\n\\nJeff Buenz, who plays Latin and jazz guitar and bass.\\nBarbary Grant, who plays Celtic music and traditional songs on the Irish harp.\\nDona Reyes, who plays classical Spanish guitar music.\\nDavid Snellbacher, who plays an assortment of guitar music including old English, Celtic, classical and traditional Christmas carols and contemporary music.\\nTo arrange a visit during your stay, call guest services at 650-962-5836.",
        "createdAt": "2020-01-14T23:40:11.206Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-01-14T23:40:29.049Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "campus": "5e00fe557ecc0b000e1c0fa1",
        "children": [],
        "photo": "/uploads/7b12ed03a6f342caae96d6e69df8180a.jpg",
        "id": "5e1e515bbf265e000eb355cc"
    }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

final class Amenity : Codable {
    var id: String
    var hasChildren: Bool
    var name: String
    var fullName: String?
    var phone: String?
    var redirectLink: String?
    var moreInfoLink: String?
    var description: String?
    var businessDays: [BusinessDays] = []
    var children: [Amenity] = []

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case businessDays = "businessdays"
        case hasChildren = "hasChild"
        case name = "name"
        case phone = "phoneNumer"
        case moreInfoLink = "moreInfoLink"
        case redirectLink = "redirectLink"
        case fullName = "fullName"
        case description = "desc"
        case children = "children"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        businessDays = try values.decodeIfPresent([BusinessDays].self, forKey: .businessDays) ?? [BusinessDays]()
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        children = try values.decodeIfPresent([Amenity].self, forKey: .children) ?? [Amenity]()
        hasChildren = try values.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .hasChildren) ?? false
        phone = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .phone)
        fullName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .fullName)
        redirectLink = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .redirectLink)
        description = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .description)
        moreInfoLink = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .moreInfoLink)

    }
}

final class BusinessDays: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var hours: [Hour]
    var daysOfWeek: String
    var displayName: String?
}

final class Hour: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var startTime: String
    var endTime: String
    var groupName: String
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

let amenities = try! decoder.decode([Amenity].self, from: json)
print(amenities)
```

Comment: Yep, I'm decoding an array of them:                     let amenities = try JSONDecoder().decode([Amenity].self, from: data!)

Comment: did you make any changes?

Comment: maybe its the utf8 thing

Comment: I didn't make any changes per se, but the JSON listing wasn't in a Swift-y form (String or Data), so I just did what I would normally do with JSON: escape "\n" to "\\n" and convert to Data.

Comment: when i get it as a response it's already in the Data form. Not sure if I have to do transforms on it? This worked elsewhere tho

Comment: If you want me to look, would you update your post with the code you use for fetching and decoding. I'm happy to have a look.

Comment: Appreciate it. Added what I can add.

Comment: The API call looks fine. And as long as you are getting JSON similar to what is in your post just before the the decode, it looks like it should work fine.